# Is there a reason for a landlord to have more General Liability Insurance than the tenant?

Tags: insurance

A prospective tenant wants me to have $2M / $4M General Liability Insurance and they only want to provide $1M / $2M. Is there a reason for this on a one year lease agreement that can be renewed annually? (They are a public university.)

Comment: You must be kidding — operating $ millions and not engaging a lawyer to deliver you answers they would be responsible for, and instead asking random people on the Internet.

Comment: @Greendrake these are actually quite low insurance limits -$20 million is far more typical for commercial policies.

Comment: @Greendrake It is totally valid and smart for the OP to do his own research prior to, or in lieu of, wasting his money on attorneys. In general, a lawyer does not really educate his clients on the legal aspects of their inquiries. Furthermore, it is obvious that the numbers the OP mentions refer to insurance *benefits*, not the premium

Comment: @DaleM The leased space is less than 2000 square feet. But why would they suggest different limits on General Liability limits for insurance.